# Is there a python-pptx function that is able to read the background color of a table cell?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-pptx

I'm trying to read the background color of a cell in a table in a pptx file with python-pptx module, but I am only able to set a `_Cell`'s fill property, not able to read a value from it.

I tried reading `fill.back_color`, but they were all (255,255,255) after doing `fill.patternize()` as the output suggests. What am I doing wrong? Or should I use another package?

My pptx file was not made with python.

Comment: Try `fill.fore_color`. `.back_color` is generally only used for pattern fills.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @scanny pointed out, `fill.back_color` is used for pattern fills. For the cell color, I should read from `fill.fore_color`.